# How to get user instance while registration in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am creating ecommerce website. I am using django auth model to create Registration and Login, and now, I wanted to add phone number in another model with user instance, in order to implement ***otp***. But, I am having trouble to get user instance while registration. So, how can I get request.user while registration. Looking for your please.
***views.py***

```
def Register(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    phonenumber = request.POST.get('phone')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            ***Profile.objects.create(user=request.user,phonenumber=phonenumber)***
            return redirect('login')
    context = {
    'form':form,
    }
```

***models.py***

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(verbose_name="Номер телефона", max_length=15)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Подтверждено", null=True, blank=True)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `save` method of `CreateUserForm` will return the created User

```py
    form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        Profile.objects.create(user=user, phonenumber=phonenumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that worked for me was the following:

```
Profile.objects.create(user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id), phonenumber=phonenumber)
```

You only need an instance of the user from the User model. So I believe that'll resolve the problem.